# TensorFlow with single output neuron

Tags: python, tensorflow

I’m fairly new to TensorFlow and I’ve been watching tutorials that use the `mnist` dataset to classify images.

These videos (or the ones that I watched) have 10 output neurons corresponding to the class of each image. e.g.
neuron 1 is Ankle boot; neuron 2 is Shirt...

These neurons output a probability but what if I only want one output neuron that returns a value from 1-10?

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

train_images = train_images/255.0
test_images = test_images/255.0

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
    ])


model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)

predictions = model.predict(test_images)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
for i in range(5):
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(test_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[test_labels[i]])
    plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[i])])
    plt.show()
```

How would I got about doing this? Or is this not possible here.

I’m using Python 3

Comment: Look at this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tensorflow/tensorflow_single_layer_perceptron.htm

Comment: You get it dear?

Comment: No I do not understand how this helps me In my problem

Comment: let me show you mnist example it has 10 outputs.

Comment: Could you show code you've tried so then I can start from it to help you. Else I've pas code here and may be you won't understand.

Comment: I have added the code i use

Comment: You’re using keras implementation, tf is more handy and detailed. Let me answer once I get my computer if someone else did not.

Answer (score 0):

The prediction from keras will cantain the probability that the item belongs to cercain class. To get the class of the item you just need to find the location of the max value with `classes = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)`